# memory_get_peak_usage(true) PHP and Virtual Memory Size resource usage are very different

Tags: php, curl, memory, cron

I have a PHP script which runs many http requests via curl - I use a variation on Rolling Curl (curl_multi) so that the requests can be run simultaneously. The script runs every few minutes with cron.

It is on a VPS and I received some 'Excessive resource usage' warnings from lfd (ConfigServer Security & Firewall) because the resource usage of the script went over the threshold of 512MB.

An example notification is:

Resource:     Virtual Memory Size

Exceeded:     582 > 512 (MB)

Executable:   /path/to/php-cgi

Command Line: /path/to/myscript.php

So I upped the threshold to 800MB and recorded the memory usage of the script using `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` every time the script runs.

However, the results from `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` are consistently 2MB... which is nowhere near the Virtual Memory usage as seen in the warning.

Note - only one instance of the script runs as multiple instances are prevented using flock.

So what am I missing?

**Update - virtual memory usage also greater than php.ini memory_limit**

After upping the threshold to 800MB I still get occasional notifications from lfd. I also checked the php.ini settings and memory_limit is set to 256MB - in theory the script wouldn't run if it was using more than this. From this I am guessing that either:

a) It is not PHP that is using the memory (could it be MySQL or CURL - is the memory used by these included in the value from`memory_get_peak_usage(true)`?)

b) I'm not getting an accurate figure from lfd

**Second Update - memory used by MySQL is not included in memory_get_peak_usage(true)**

I suspect this is the issue - however I'm not sure what exactly CSF includes in resource figure. I will look into making the MySQL requests more efficient and see how that effects things.

Comment: `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` only retrieves the usage of the currently running script, how long does your script take to run, is it possible that many instances of the process are running at a given time?

Comment: The script runs for anywhere between 0.1 and 20 seconds but there should only ever be one instance of the script running as I am preventing multiple instances with flock

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. The script runs for less than 0.02 seconds, but it seems it amounts to over 312MB of memory usage ("Virtual Memory Size") according to CSF/LFD. Could it be that resources are not being freed when calling PHP from the command line (also through cron, in my case)?

Comment: @zmippie - what I've learned since I posted a couple of years ago is that the memory usage CSF/LFD is reporting is Virtual Memory and not real memory. Also, the memory usage shown by CSF/LFD is not accurate and there is a lot more memory available than the readings would suggest. We've scaled the processes considerably in the past couple of years and would get warnings of memory usage well beyond what the server would be capable of handling. However the load on the server stayed low throughout. In the end we turned the notifications off as they were not useful.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the info, much appreciated! So CSF/LFD's reporting is a bit murky. Haven't seen the CSF/LFD notice for a few days now, so it may had something to do with errors getting thrown in the script (there was a bug in it, it was fixed shorty after my message). It'll be interesting to know if script errors have anything to do with it. Maybe in the future, when I have time to spare ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `memory_get_usage` family of functions tracks the state of PHP's internal memory manager, which is responsible for all memory directly used by things like PHP variables. This is also what is limited by the `memory_limit` setting - after the limit is reached, the internal memory manager will refuse to claim more RAM from the OS.

However, not all the RAM used by your process is allocated via that memory manager. For instance, third party libraries like CURL or the MySQL connection library will have memory allocation completely independent of PHP, because they are effectively separate programs being executed by the PHP engine. Another example is that opening a file might cause it to be mapped into memory by the OS kernel, even if you never read its contents into a PHP variable.

This [talk by Julien Pauli at PHP UK a few years ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm1HUrnsxLI) goes into more details on the different types of memory usage, and how to measure them.